# How to write values to depth buffer in godot fragment shader?

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

How do you specify the depth value in the fragment shader, if you would like to for example render a texture of a sphere that also affect depht buffer in the cameras z-direction?

In OpenGL you can use `gl_FragDepth`. Is there a similar builtin variable in godot?

Edit:
I found that there is a variable `DEPTH` after posting the question that [seems to be merged](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/22800).. I have not had time to try it yet. If you have any experience from using successfully, I would accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write to `DEPTH` from the fragment buffer of the shader of an spatial material.

Godot will, of course, also draw depth by default. You can control that with the render modes `depth_draw_*`, see [Depth Draw Mode](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/spatial_material.html#depth-draw-mode).

And if you want to read depth, you can use `DEPTH_TEXTURE`. The article [Screen Reading Shaders](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/screen-reading_shaders.html#depth-texture) has an example.

Refer to [Spatial Shader](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/spatial_shader.html) for the list available variables and options in spatial shaders.